# suse isc dhcpd dhcrelay no ipaddress

Tags: dhcp, sles, isc-dhcp

I have the following setup:

```
Client --> eth2(10.4.0.1/16) - router / - eth1(10.3.0.1/16) --> dhcp-server(10.3.0.150)
                              dhcp-relay
```

If the client starts a dhcp-request it receives the dhcp-relay and the dhcp-relay forwards this request to the dhcp-server:

```
IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from << MAC >> (oui Unknown), length 340
```

The dhcp-server receives this request and sends a reply to the routers interface on client side:

```
IP 10.3.0.1.bootps > 10.3.0.150.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from b8:27:eb:61:ef:c1 (oui Unknown), length 340
IP 10.3.0.150.bootps > 10.0.4.1.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

But this reply is never reaching the client who started the request. For testing all firewalls are disabled, so that there are no packages dropped...

Answer (score 0):

Should the subnet mask be /8 as /16 that would make 10.3.0.1 and 10.4.0.1 be on different ranges?

```
/8  = 255.0.0.0 
/16 = 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: No, the subnet mask is right. If I would use /8 as subnet mask the network would go from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 and the clients wold be in the same subnet. That's no possible...